# Modules with rank and localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

This question is from my assignment of localization of modules and I need help with it.

> Let A be a non-zero commutative ring. $S_0$ be the multiplicatively closed subset of non-zero  divisors in A and $Q(A)= S_{0}^{-1}A $ be the total quotient ring of A. An A-module V is called a module with rank over A if $S_{0}^{-1} V$ is  a free Q(A) module; we also say that V has rank over A and put $Rank_A V= Rank_{Q(A)} S_{0}^{-1} V$.

(a) Every free A-module V is an A-module with rank and in this case its rank  is the   rank of the free A-module V.

I have done this.

(b)  If A is an integral domain, then Q(A) is the quotient field of A and hence every A-module has a rank and $Rank_A V= \dim_{Q(A)} S_{0}^{-1}V$.

How to construct basis of A-module in this case?

(c) If V is an A-module with rank , then $S_{0}^{-1} V$ has a Q(A)- basis of the type $x_i /1$ $i\in I$ and $x_i , i\in I$ is a maximal linearly independent (over A) family in V.

V is an A-module with rank means that $S_{0}^{-1} V$ is a free Q(A) module means there exists a basis. I have been given $x_i's$ are maximal Linearly independent set for V , it must also generate V as if it doesn't an element say v then { $v, x_i $} is a L I set , hence {$x_i's$} is not maximal LI set.  So, this part is easy to complete and I have done it.

(d) Every finite torsion free A-module with rank is isomorphic to a A-submodule of a finite free A-module.

Well, any submodule of a free A-module will also be free and if in the basis of V there exists an element $a \in A$ which is not torsional free then I have av=0 , which will force v =0 which is a contradiction. Any submodule of V and V itself are torsion free but how should I prove that an isomorphism exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few misunderstandings in what you say, so let's go through them.

b) You do not need to construct a basis of an $A$-module here.  All you need is that every vector space (e.g. module over the field $Q(A)$) has a basis.

c) No, the $x_i$ do not necessarily generate $V$.  A set can be maximal linearly independent, without generating the module.  For example regard $\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over itself.  Then $\{2\}$ is a maximal linearly independent set.  Thus $\{2,3\}$ is not linearly independent: $2\times 3-3\times 2=0$.  However $3$ is not in the span of $2$.

In fact you do not need to show the $x_i$ generate $V$ here.  You are not "given" the $x_i$ are maximal linearly independent.  You need to deduce it:

Any $v\in S_0^{-1}V$ has the form: $$v=s^{-1}\left(\sum_i a_i x_i) \right),$$ with $s\in S_0$ and $a_i\in A$.  Thus $$vs-\left(\sum_i a_i x_i) \right)=0,$$ so $\{x_i|i\in I,v\}$ is not linearly independent over $A$.

d) No a submodule of a free module is not necessarily free.  Consider $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ as a module over itself. Then neither factor of $\mathbb{Q}$ is free.

The point here is that because $V$ is torsion free, it embeds in $S_0^{-1}V$, which has a basis $\frac {x_i}1$ over $Q(A)$.  As $V$ is finitely generated, all its generators are contained in the span of the $\frac {x_i}s$, for some fixed $s\in S$.  It remains only to show that the $\frac {x_i}s$ are linearly independent over $A$, which follows from the fact that they are linearly independent over $Q(A)$.

Thus we can conclude that over $A$, the  $\frac {x_i}s$ span a free $A$-module, which contains $V$.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that every vector space has a basis but how will it help in (b)?

Comment: I am aware of the definition of Linear independence but how does $ vs -(\sum_i a_i x_i) =0$ implies that {$x_i$} is not Linear independent over A? Also , can you help with proving how {$x_i$} is a maximal  LI set over V?

Comment: In (b) $Q(A)$ is a field.  A module over a field is a vector space (definition of vector space).  Every vector space has a basis.  Therefore it is free (definition of free).

Comment: You misread.  I did not claim the $\{x_i\}$ are not linearly independent over $A$.  I said that $\{x_i\}\cup \{v\}$ are not linearly independent over $A$.

Comment: This is precisely the meaning of maximal linearly independent set: It is linearly independent, and if you throw in any extra element $v$, then it stops being linearly independent.

Comment: I understand how I was wrong in (c). Can you please help in proving how $S_0^{-1}V$ has Q(A) basis of the type $frac{x_i} {1}$?

Comment: By definition of $module$ $with$ $rank$ $S_0^{-1}V$ has a $Q(A)$ basis of the form $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$, where $y_i\in S_0$.  Then each $y_i$ is a unit in $Q(A)$, and multiplying the elements of a basis by units, results in a basis.  In particular we may multiply each  $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ by $y_i$ to get $\frac{x_i}{1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!